# JPQL multiple MEMBER OF

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm wondering if there is any JPQL construct that might help me with this problem:

Imagine simple M-N relationship of Chat and User (user might be present in multiple chat-s).

```
public class ChatEntity implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = UserEntity.class)
@JoinTable(name = "CHATS_USERS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHAT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
private Collection<User> users;

}
```

Lets imagine these data (C1..CN = chat IDs, U1..UN = user IDs)

```
c1 ~ {u1, u2, u3} // in chat1 is user1, user2 and user3
c2 ~ {u1, u3}
c3 ~ {u2, u3}
```

Now I want to select such chat which has exact same collection of users i will pass to the query. E.g.

```
{u1, u3} -> c2
{u1, u2, u3} -> c1
{u1, u2} -> NULL (no result)
```

I found MEMBER OF constuct which seems nice. E.g.

```
SELECT c FROM Chat c WHERE (:u1 MEMBER OF c.users) AND (:u2 MEMBER OF c.users)
    ... AND (:uN MEMBER OF c.users)
```

But now there are two problems

1. This is not correct so far because *{u1, u3}* will return both *c1* and *c2* and not only *c2* as expected
2. I got the collection of users and I don't know if there is a way how to "decompose" such collection to multiple AND clauses in **named query** (static definition of query) or if there is any JPQL construct which will help me with this. E.g. something like

   ... WHERE :users = c.users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... you want the users to only include those Users?

Perhaps also include

```
AND size(c.users) = 3
```

Or maybe,

```
Select c from Chat c join c.users u where not exists (Select u from User u2 where u = u2 and u.id not in :ids)
```

Comment: the size did it. Actually it is not that nice (adding new parameter), but it satisfies:)